# js RegEx conditional replace with captured group

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to format a url using regex in javascript...

Input: `http://www.google.com` or `https://www.yahoo.com`

I am using this regex to capture `/(http\:\/\/|https\:\/\/){0,1}(.*)/`

so `$1` is saying is it `http` or `https` and `$2` rest of the url...

Now I want to replace `http` with `1` and `https` with `2` so that the output should like below:

`1www.google.com` and `2www.yahoo.com`

I used the below code but it's not working...

```
var url = "http://www.microsoft.com";
url.replace(/(http\:\/\/|https\:\/\/){0,1}(.*)/, ("$1"=="http://"?"1":"2")+"$2");
// output: 2www.microsoft.com

url.replace(/(http\:\/\/|https\:\/\/){0,1}(.*)/, ("$1"=="http://")+"$2");
// output: falsewww.microsoft.com
```

Anybody know how to do that...?? thanks...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A solution using your regex

```
var url1= 'http://www.google.com';
var url2= 'https://www.yahoo.com';
url1.replace(/(http\:\/\/|https\:\/\/){0,1}(.*)/, function (g1,g2,g3) { 
    var prefix =''; 
    if(g2 == 'https://') {
        prefix = '2'
    } else{ 
        prefix='1'
    } 
    return prefix + g3
})
//url1.replace(...) //"1www.google.com"
//url2.replace(...) //"2www.yahoo.com"
```

Answer (score 2):

regexp you are using isn't good: it can match http in the middle of the string and it tries to match whole string even though it is not needed

use this instead

```
url.replace(/^http(s)?:\/\//, function(match, secure) {
    return secure ? "2" : "1"
})
```

Answer (score 1):

`url.replace('https','2').replace('http','1')`

Not sure why you would want to do this though

Comment: I want the solution using regex... so of course there should be a reason for that... my real problem is more complex and I want to use a single regex replace instead of 15 replace like yours...

Answer (score 0):

```
url.replace(/(http\:\/\/|https\:\/\/){0,1}(.*)/,function($1, $2, $3) {
    if($2 == 'https://') {
        return "2" + $3
    } else {
        return "1" + $3
    }
});
```

**Explanation - How replace function works with RegEx**

```
replace(<RegEx>, handler)
```

Parameters - $1, $2, $3 ... are result of the RegEx. Each captured group in the regular expression pattern can be used within the replacement string using the $N notation, where "N" is the index of the captured group:

Comment: you answered the same thing xecgr answered... you should put a up vote instead...

Answer (score -1):

```
url.replace(/(http\:\/\/|https\:\/\/){0,1}(.*)/, ("$1"=="http://"?"1":"2")+"$2");
```

should do the trick without having to introduce lambda functions and with minimal modification to your existing code.  The problem with your regex is that you were capturing the `://` and not comparing with that, and `"http://" == "http"` will always evaluate to false.

Comment: thanks for your answer... I wrote it wrong in my question... even if you compare with `http://` it says `false`...