# Regex to convert a date to another format

Tags: regex

I am using regex to manage a url redirect. I want to convert a url like this:

```
/18th-September-2019
```

To

```
/18-09-2019
```

So far I have the following regex pair that grabs the separate parts of the url:

```
^/(.*)-(.*)-(.*)
/$1-$2-$3
```

But I do not know how to add in the conversion. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Regex doesn't have the functionality to find and replace like that. Ex: you can't say IF `$2` is '09', then replace with 'September'. You should use a programming language or other something that can parse the date and write a different way. How were you going to use the Regex?

Comment: This will be added to a plugin on Wordpress (https://redirection.me/). The solution from MonkeyZeus works well.

Comment: Cool! Glad you found a solution. I didn't really think about 12 separate regex statements, but if the shoe fits...

Comment: @dvo ahem, make that 24 separate regexes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what environment or programming language you are using but you would essentially need 24 regexes and 24 replacements:

```
...
\/(\d)[^\d]*?-September-(\d{4})
\/(\d{2})[^\d]*?-September-(\d{4})
\/(\d)[^\d]*?-October-(\d{4})
\/(\d{2})[^\d]*?-October-(\d{4})
...
```

https://regex101.com/r/4ivC5H/1 - single digit

https://regex101.com/r/17ymUl/1 - double digit

---

As a side note:

With JS you can perform conditional replacements via anonymous functions but that is a language-specific feature. https://stackoverflow.com/a/24537032/2191572

Comment: Thanks. That's a neat solution and has worked well.

Comment: @Kev You're welcome. I see that you mentioned a Wordpress plugin in your comment so if it's available to you then [preg_replace_callback()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) could be used to achieve a conditional replacement.

Comment: Thanks for that tip. I have just noticed another issue. That snippet works on dates with two digits (i.e. 10th -31st), but for those with only 1 (e.g. 1st) is there a way to convert that to "01", for example currently 1st September would be converted to 1-09-2019, instead of 01-09-2019

Comment: @Kev If `preg_replace_callback()` is not an option then you would have to do 24 different regexes and replacements to achieve that. See my update.

Comment: @Kev Any luck with this?

Comment: Oh yes, I nearly forgot :) Thanks again!